# Show that if two distributions have the same kernel, then one is a constant multiple of the other.

Tags: distribution-theory

If the set of test function corresponding to the kernel of distribution f coincides with the kernel of distribution g, then the distribution f is a constant multiple of g.

Comment: Distributions are just linear functionals.

Answer (score 1):

Set $K =\ker f = \ker g$. Quotienting, we obtain isomorphisms of vector spaces $\tilde f,\tilde g :\mathcal D/K \to \mathbb R$, which means that $\tilde f \tilde g^{-1}$ is an isomorphism between vector spaces $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. The only such maps are multiplication by constants. To finish, note that $f = \tilde f \tilde g^{-1} g$.

Comment: (assuming of course that $f,g$ are not identically $0$)